# Calling a method Update

Tags: java, class, methods, actionlistener

I'm making a simple program that updates the amount of times you click, here's my actionlistener:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class clickActionListener implements ActionListener {
Class1 object = new Class1();

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        object.click();
        }}
```

***This is my click method in my class1 class:

```
public void click(){
        clicks++;
        label.setText("You clicked "+ clicks+" times");
    }
```

It does not work. But when I delete my click class and put the contents of it into the actionlistener itself (assume I associated everything correctly), it works:

```
public class clickActionListener implements ActionListener {
Class1 object = new Class1();
int click;
JLabel label2;
    public clickListener(int clicks, JLabel label) {
    click = clicks;
    label2 = label;
}
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        click++;
        label2.setText("You clicked "+ click+" times");
    }
```

If anyone can tell me what I'm doing wrong, I'd greatly appreciate it. Thanks and sorry for the messy post.

***Update

Sorry for not being clear, by "does not work" I mean the jlabel does not update and stays at 0.

This is the Class1 code that "does not work"

```
    import java.awt.Gridlayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public Class1{
int clicks=0;
JLabel label=new JLabel("You clicked "+clicks+" times.");
public void method(){
JFrame frame=new JFrame();
JButton button=new JButton("Click this");
button.addActionListener(new clickActionListener());
frame.add(button):
frame.add(label);
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
}
public void clicks(){
clicks++;
label.setText("You clicked "+clicks+" times"):}}
```

The Class1 that does work is the same as above only I get rid of the click() method and put the JLabel and int into the 'new clicklistener(clicks, label)'

Comment: Please define: "It does not work". Do you get any errors/exceptions/incorrect results? Also please provide short but full code example which will let us reproduce your problem.

Comment: Can you post code for your Class1?

Comment: I posted an update to clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is easy. Your actionListener is holding reference to different `Class1` Object then the one you see on screen.

Try passing `Class1` instance as a constructor parameter and everything will be fine. Try something like this:

in clickListener replace
`Class1 object = new Class1();` with contructor

```
Class1 object;
public clickListener(Class1 obj){
    object=obj;
}
```

and in Class1 use our constructor.

```
button.addActionListener(new clickActionListener(this));
```

not it will work.